# How to check if pthread progressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, posix, deadlock

I need to write simple watchdog which could detect deadlocks in iOS.
I already implemented simple one using GCD dispatch source working as a timer which increments  a counter (dispatching on main thread).

This works quite nice for detecting if main thread did stuck but I would like to improve it by being able **to detect deadlock on any thread**.

My idea is for periodically loop throughout all threads and compare thread backtraces between checks, but I am not sure it it is good approach:

PSEUDO-CODE:

```
const task_t    this_task = mach_task_self();
const thread_t  this_thread = mach_thread_self();

kern_return_t kr;
thread_act_array_t threads;
mach_msg_type_number_t thread_count;
kr = task_threads(this_task, &threads, &thread_count);

for (mach_msg_type_number_t i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {

    // 0. get thread:
    thread_t thread = threads[i];
    // 1. do not analyze this thread (it is an watchdog thread):
    if (this_thread == thread)continue;
    // 2. suspend thread for a moment:
    if((kr = thread_suspend(thread)) != KERN_SUCCESS)continue;
    // 3. get backtrace:
    int backtraceLength = ksbt_backtraceThread(thread, (uintptr_t*)backtrace, sizeof(backtrace));
    // 4. todo - compare.... (HOW TO???)
```

Anyone can help if **comparing backtraces is good approach to detect if thread did stuck** or is there better POSIX method?

Comment: Look at OSAtomic.h - your background thread can update a counter thread safe. Use the barrier version(s)